# how to display UIActivityindicator in UITableView on iphone

Tags: iphone

i struggled almost 1 hour but i couldn't  figure it out as how to display UIactivity indicator in UItableview as i cant use IB in UItableview(its not dragging) on iphone

i used this and its working 
but i want to display in viewDidload

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

//loadingView =[LoadingView loadingViewInView:[self.view.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0]];//.window.subviews
    NSLog(@"dgdddddddddddddddddddd");
    UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 10, 25, 25)];

    //UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 30.0, 320.0, 60.0)];
    activityView.center=customView.center;
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [ customView bringSubviewToFront:activityView];
    [customView addSubview:activityView];// [headerLabel release];

    return [customView autorelease];       
}
```

kindly suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the view attribute of the file is linked to the UITableView , then the subview will not be added. Try replacing the view attribute with a normal view which contains a table view and try adding the indicator. Also try to make the file owner class from uitableviewcontroller to uiviewcontroller class.

Comment: I am just so perplexed! Why is it so? The viewController's view property makes least difference here since the activity indicator is being added on the header view as a subview. What does the viewController's view property has to do with it?

Comment: @Raj because when you scroll or reload tableview , all cells , headers and footers are stacked on top of UITableview while removing the previous one.

Comment: I am not convinced / understanding it, the question stated that he was not able to drag UITableView in IB, so I assume that he wanted to add it as a subview to the whole tableView. In which case, why isnt it possible using UITableViewController + xib?